# How to Get Session Object in Loopback 3 Route using Express-Session

Tags: loopback, express-session

I found this link that shows how to add express-session as middleware however I don't know how to access the session based on the loopback model.

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/part-1-ionic-loopback-node-js-mobile/

Sorry, don't have copy/paste access to the code currently.

Example model.json file:
[model.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZcOQ.png)

Example model.js file:
[model.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJfWe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Was able to add it as an arg `{arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}}` and then use the normal req.session to get the session.

Documentation:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html